# Arcore StereoScopic Rendering in Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, google-cardboard, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I would like to implement an android application (API min 27) for a term project which enables users to experience Arcore and mixed reality features in headsets such as google cardboard etc with stereoscopic view. For preliminary research, i couldn't find valid resources and approaches in order to solve stereoscopic vision on arcore except some approaches in unity3d, openGL and some frameworks such as Vuforia etc.. As far as i know, currently arcore 1.5 is not supporting this feature.

I considered using cardboard sdk and arcore sdk together but I am not sure that it is going to be naive approach and provide solid foundation for the project and future works.

Is there a way to work around for desired stereoscopic view for Arcore in native android or how can I implement stereoscopic view for given case (Not asking for actual implementation, just brainstorming) ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/jondyne/ARcore_mobileVRHeadset/) and [this](https://github.com/ChristophGeske/ARCoreInsideOutTrackingGearVr)

Answer (score 0):

there is the Google Sceneform - scenegraph-based visualization engine for AR applications and there is [this feature request](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/236) asking for the same thing you have planned. Now to answer your question, there is [this java visualization library](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali) used throughout google's own ARCore examples and it has [support for stereoscopic rendering](https://github.com/ejeinc/RajawaliCardboardExample/blob/master/rajawali/src/main/java/org/rajawali3d/renderer/RajawaliSideBySideRenderer.java). What is missing in their implementation is accounting for lens distortion.